# How to access controls in code loaded inside colorbox popup in code behind

Tags: asp.net

Scenario: I'm invoking a popup [colorbox] href="#inline2" as depicted below:

```
 <a class="inline addnew loc" href="#inline2">Add New Location</a>
```

The above code will load the following i.e  on the popup as depicted below. The popup along with the content is invoked successfully, but the controls are not accessible in the code behind.

What we tried: The controls are accessible via page methods, but we want to access the controls directly without any page methods.

```
 <div style="display: none;">
            <div id="inline2" runat="server">
                <div class="popupbox">
                    <div class="menu_category service ltitle">
                        <h3>+ Add New Location</h3>
                        <div class="addservices newlocation">

                                <div class="fld">
                                    <label class="lineh">
                                        Location
                                        <br />
                                        Name</label>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="lname1" CssClass="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="popupmenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="done">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="done" runat="server" OnClientClick="newLocation_Click()">Done</asp:LinkButton>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /#sidebar-right -->
        </div>
```

Expected: We want to access the controls in the code behind without using page methods.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by 'without using page methods'. One thing that doesn't seem correct is <form> tag. Can you try to add Id attribute and runat="server" attribute to that form.

Comment: 'withot using page methods' means i want to access the controls in the code behind: E.g TextBox1.text="hello";

Comment: Add those attributes to <form> or try to remove that tag from above code, there is form surrounding your entire page anyway. Every control you want to access must have runat="server" attribute.

Comment: I tried to remove the tag from above code, as well as added runat="server", but still does not work..

Comment: Can u pls help me to resolve the issue..i tried the above but still does not works?

Comment: Can you add code-behind where you try to access Server control (lname1 TextBox) from your popup div?

Comment: Finaly solved the issue..i just downloaded the latest ver of colorbox & added a reference to my project & worked perfectly.